# Cant retrieve user info from database when running query, codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having an issue, it should be very simple but I can't seem to fix it. I am trying to grab a user id from a user by searching the username in the database. But i am just getting a null value.. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong.

Here is the code for the query:

```
private function get_u_id($user){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'username'=?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user));
    foreach($query->result as $row){
    return $row['id'];
    }
}
```

I am storing this info in a session so here is that code:

```
$user_session_data = array(
   'user'=>$p_info['username'],
   'email' => $this->get_user_email($p_info['username']),
   'u_id' => $this->get_u_id($p_info['username']),
   'validated' => TRUE
);

//set a session, (username, email, user_id)

private function set_session($user_data) {
        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
    }
```

And when I output this session using print_r() it looks like this

```
[user_data] => [user] => wilprim [email] => [u_id] => [validated] => 1
```

Comment: pretty inefficient, running two queries to get two different fields from the same record, back-to-back. you'd be better off doing a `select id, email from ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got incorrect quotes in the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'username'=?";
                                  ^--      ^--
```

`'username'` is a **STRING**, not a fieldname. `username` is also not a reserved word, so there's absolutely no need to quote it anyways.

User either of:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username`=?"; // note the backticks
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?"; // no quotes at all
```

As written, the only way your query would ever return any data is if you had a user whose username was literally `username`.

Comment: I just tried this and still no u_id.. I am thinking it must be something that has to do with the username being search for, which is weird because that is being set fine in the session...

Comment: am i doing the foreach correctly, and returning the value correctly?

Comment: you may want to redesign have a generic "getUserInfo" function, rather than having one-function-per-field. Returning a few extra/unwanted fields will have lower overhead than having to run one-query-per-field. but otherwise, what you're doing is fine. just fix the query syntax.

Comment: ended up getting it when making a getUserInfo() function! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using CI's active record class to achieve what you need, but in a much cleaner way, for instance :

```
private function get_u_id($user){
   $query = $this->db->select('id')->from('users')->where('username', $user)->limit(1)->get();
   return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row()->id : 0;
}
```

L.E:
@cipherous in your example:
It is `$query->result()` (to return an array of objects) or `$query->result_array()` (to return an array of arrays) not `$query->result` .
If you want a single row, you will use `$query->row()` (object) and `$query->row_array()` (array) and you don't have to loop over it.

Comment: Next time, please explain your answer. Simply pasting code is not the proper format for StackOverflow, or any SE site.

Comment: Really, i think the code is self explanatory ;) i gave a solution, i don't have to explain it.

Comment: A great answer is above you. I'm sorry if you think your quality is enough, but for anyone that comes here from Google with the same problem and they see a code block that doesn't pertain to their codebase, they have no idea what's going on